# Python program to convert a 24 hour format to 12 hour format

Tags: python, beginner, datetime, formatting

Given a string in a 24 hour format the program outputs a 12 hour format. The rules are:

- The output format must be 'hh:mm a.m.' if it represents before midday and 'hh:mm p.m.' after midday
- When the hour is less than 10:00 you should not write a 0 before the hour, example: '9:05 a.m.'

For example:

12:30 → 12:30 p.m.
09:00 → 9:00 a.m.
23:15 → 11:15 p.m.

The code:

```
import datetime
def time_converter(time):
    midday_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime('12:00','%H:%M')
    time_dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, '%H:%M')

    if time_dt >= midday_dt:
        if time_dt >= datetime.datetime.strptime('13:00','%H:%M'):
            hours, minutes = clamp_to_twelve(time_dt, midday_dt)
            time = f'{hours}:{minutes}'
        time += ' p.m.'
    else:
        if time_dt < datetime.datetime.strptime('10:00','%H:%M'):
            time = time[1:]
        if is_midnight(time_dt):
            hours, minutes = clamp_to_twelve(time_dt, midday_dt)
            time = f'{hours}:{minutes:02d}'
        time += ' a.m.'
    return time

def clamp_to_twelve(time_dt, midday_dt):
    clamp_dt = time_dt - midday_dt
    minutes, seconds = divmod(clamp_dt.seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    return [hours, minutes]

def is_midnight(time_dt):
    return (time_dt >= datetime.datetime.strptime('00:00','%H:%M') and
        time_dt <= datetime.datetime.strptime('00:59','%H:%M'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert time_converter('12:30') == '12:30 p.m.'
    assert time_converter('09:00') == '9:00 a.m.'
    assert time_converter('23:15') == '11:15 p.m.'
```

Answer (score 1):

To help with readability, I'd just import `datetime.datetime` and then alias it, that way you aren't typing `datetime.datetime` all over the place:

```py
from datetime import datetime as dt

def time_converter(time):
    midday_dt = dt.strptime('12:00','%H:%M')
    time_dt = dt.strptime(time, '%H:%M')

    if time_dt >= midday_dt:
        if time_dt >= dt.strptime('13:00','%H:%M'):
            hours, minutes = clamp_to_twelve(time_dt, midday_dt)
            time = f'{hours}:{minutes}'
        time += ' p.m.'
    else:
        if time_dt < dt.strptime('10:00','%H:%M'):
            time = time[1:]
        if is_midnight(time_dt):
            hours, minutes = clamp_to_twelve(time_dt, midday_dt)
            time = f'{hours}:{minutes:02d}'
        time += ' a.m.'
    return time

def clamp_to_twelve(time_dt, midday_dt):
    clamp_dt = time_dt - midday_dt
    minutes, seconds = divmod(clamp_dt.seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    return [hours, minutes]

def is_midnight(time_dt):
    return (time_dt >= dt.strptime('00:00','%H:%M') and
        time_dt <= dt.strptime('00:59','%H:%M'))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    assert time_converter('12:30') == '12:30 p.m.'
    assert time_converter('09:00') == '9:00 a.m.'
    assert time_converter('23:15') == '11:15 p.m.'
```

Next, if you are just unpacking the `list` returned from `clamp_to_twelve`, I would just return a `tuple`:

```py
def clamp_to_twelve(time_dt, midday_dt):
    clamp_dt = time_dt - midday_dt
    minutes, seconds = divmod(clamp_dt.seconds, 60)
    hours, minutes = divmod(minutes, 60)
    return hours, minutes
```

This saves you from having to construct the list, as well as the additional overhead of over-allocating memory to take into account the mutable `list`.

As a last optimization, you could refactor your `if` statements to not be nested. Because you are using `if if` rather than `if elif`, all of your statements are executed within the nested blocks:

```py
def time_converter(time):
    midday_dt = dt.strptime('12:00','%H:%M')
    time_dt = dt.strptime(time, '%H:%M')

    if time_dt >= dt.strptime('13:00', '%H:%M'):
        hours, minutes = clamp_to_twelve(time_dt, midday_dt)
        time = f'{hours}:{minutes} p.m.'

    elif time_dt > midday_dt:
        time += ' p.m.'

    elif time_dt < dt.strptime('10:00', '%H:%M'):
        time = f'{time[1:]} a.m.'

    elif is_midnight(time_dt):
        hours, minutes = clamp_to_twelve(time_dt, midday_dt)
        time = f'{hours}:{minutes} a.m.'

    else:
        time += ' a.m.'

    return time
```

The only issue being that the order is quite important, since `time_dt > midday_dt` and `time_dt >= dt.strptime('13:00', '%H:%M')` are not mutually exclusive. However, you do get a slight time bump because of the separation of blocks of code:

```py
python -m timeit -s "from file import time_converter, time_converter_2; times = ['12:30', '09:00', '11:15']" '(time_converter(t) for t in times)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.275 usec per loop

python -m timeit -s "from file import time_converter, time_converter_2; times = ['12:30', '09:00', '11:15']" '(time_converter_2(t) for t in times)'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.277 usec per loop
```

Emphasis on *slight*. Depends on what you find more readable.